# How to set equation number for each equation in PDF

Tags: pdf, xslt, dita-ot

I would like equation number for each equation in PDF tranfer ,  they are increased by 1 , as shown in  Number below.

chapter 1

```
                A= 1+2+3                  ( 1 )
```

Chpater  2

```
                B= 1+2+3                  ( 2 )
                C = 1+2+3                  ( 3 )
```

Chpater  3

```
                D= 1+2+3                  ( 4 )
```

---

Below bold codes are what I tried, but they all failed. would you please help with this ?

```
<xsl:template match="equation-block" >
    <fo:block   xsl:use-attribute-sets="equation-block" >
          <xsl:apply-templates select="*[contains(@class,' topic/image ')]"/>  
            <fo:inline  text-align="right" >
                ******<!-- Failed:    <xsl:apply-templates select="equation-number"/> -->
            <!--Failed:     <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>  -->       
                <!--Faild:     <xsl:value-of select="count(./preceding::equation-block[child::equation-block][ancestor-or-self::equation-block[position()=last()]])+1" />  -->  
            <!--Faild:     <xsl:value-of select="count(equation-block)[. &lt;&lt; current()]) + 1"/>  -->****** 
          </fo:inline>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>
```

Thanks~~

br

Lisa Zeng

Comment: What is the xml structure of the equations? Do they have an own unique tag or are they covered in text? An xml example would be great. Probably your solution would be something like: <xsl:value-of select="count(preceding::equation-block[not(descendant::equation-block)])+1" />.

Comment: Hi Christian, thanks for your suggestion  xml struction of equaiton is : <equation-block id="equation-block_XXX">
            <image href="equation-0002.mml" outputclass="center"/><equation-number/>
        </equation-block>   and right now , I used below commands, it works.    <xsl:value-of select="count(./preceding::equation-block[ancestor-or-self::equation-block[position()=last()]])+1" />    thanks,  a lot

Comment: Just to explain you your code and why I think it is wrong: preceding::equation-block takes ALL preceding equat.-blocks. If you put some []-brackets behind that statement, you select a specific subset of them, which matches the criteria. In your case your criteria is, if they are an equation-block by themself, so it is always true. You are using ancestor-or-self. If you do not want it to be true all the time delete 'or-self'. So now we are at the 2nd criteria or [last()]. This does nothing. It would SELECT only the highest equat.-block in the structure IF it would be outside of the []-brackets